# Creating a shopping cart with Context and my api

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Im using Reactjs to create an ecom store and I am pulling in all my product details from an API. I created a product page with all products and then a product detail page when clicking on a product that links to its ID. Ive been trying to use Context to store/keep track of the product ID and Quantity. What I cant figure out is how to have my Context get my current products ID/quantity and save that within to use it for at check out. Ive only been able to find examples of people using JSON files and not pulling from an API like this.

Product Detail Page that I want to save ID/Quantity from:

```
import { getProducts } from "../api";
import { Link, useParams, useLocation, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";

export function loader({ params }) {
  return getProducts(params.id);
}

export default function ProductDetials() {
  const product = useLoaderData();
  const location = useLocation();

  const search = location.state?.search || "";
  const type = location.state?.type || "all";

  return (
    <div className="product-detail-container">
      <Link to={`..${search}`} relative="path" className="back-button">
        &larr; <span>Back to {type} products</span>
      </Link>

      <div className="product-detail">
        <img className="img-size" src={`../images/${product.imageUrl}`} />

        <div className="product-description">
          <h2>{product.name}</h2>
          <p className="product-price">
            <span>{product.itemPrice}</span>
          </p>
          <p>{product.description}</p>

          <button className="link-button">Add To Cart</button>
          <i className={`product-type ${product.type} selected upperCase`}>
            {product.type}
          </i>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

API:

```
import { createServer, Model, Response } from "miragejs";

createServer({
  models: {
    products: Model,
  },

  seeds(server) {
    server.create("product", {
      id: "1",
      name: "Lock & Dam #11™ ground",
      itemPrice: "$12/Bag",
      description:
        " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aut quasi a ullam quos aliquam natus ab ipsam nulla suscipit.",
      imageUrl: "lockdamcoffee.jpeg",
      type: "coffee",
    });
    
    

  routes() {
    this.namespace = "api";
    this.logging = false;
    

    this.get("/products", (schema, request) => {
      return schema.products.all();
    });

    this.get("/products/:id", (schema, request) => {
      const id = request.params.id;
      return schema.products.find(id);
    });
}
```

Connections:

```
export async function getProducts(id) {
  const url = id ? `/api/products/${id}` : "/api/products";
  const res = await fetch(url);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw {
      message: "Failed to fetch products",
      statusText: res.statusText,
      status: res.status,
    };
  }
  const data = await res.json();
  return data.products;
}
```

Heres what Ive tried in my Context so far, but have only gotten errors after error. Ive been trying with this the last 4 days. Ive dug myself in that i am not sure where I am with it now...

```
import { createContext, ReactNode, useContext, useState } from "react"

const ShoppingCartContext = createContext()

export function useShoppingCart() {
  return useContext(ShoppingCartContext)
}
export function ShoppingCartProvider({ children }) {
  
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])

  const cartQuantity = cartItems.reduce(
    (quantity, item) => item.quantity + quantity,
    0
  )

  function getItemQuantity(id) {
    return cartItems.find(item => item.id === id)?.quantity || 0
  }
  function increaseCartQuantity(id) {
    setCartItems(currItems => {
      if (currItems.find(item => item.id === id) == null) {
        return [...currItems]
      } else {
        return currItems.map(item => {
          if (item.id === id) {
            return { ...item, item.id + 1 }
          } else {
            return item
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
  function decreaseCartQuantity(id) {
    setCartItems(currItems => {
      if (currItems.find(item => item.id === id)?.quantity === 1) {
        return currItems.filter(item => item.id !== id)
      } else {
        return currItems.map(item => {
          if (item.id === id) {
            return { ...item, it.id - 1 }
          } else {
            return item
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
  function removeFromCart(id) {
    setCartItems(currItems => {
      return currItems.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    })
  }

  return (
    <ShoppingCartContext.Provider
      value={{
        getItemQuantity,
        increaseCartQuantity,
        decreaseCartQuantity,
        removeFromCart,
        cartItems,
        cartQuantity,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ShoppingCartContext.Provider>
  )
}
```